# Calendar question in unix

Tags: awk, calendar

I want to print dates with their respective days of a particular years month.

Example entered year is 2018 and month is Feb. so output will show

```
Date.     Day  
1.        thursday
2.        Saturday
.
.
.
.
28.       Wednesday
```

Comment: yes I tried but it shows only this months all details.

Answer (score 3):

You're describing a good exercise for a beginner in linux so I won't spoon-feed you your homework but I will answer to help you do it.

Start by learning how to use the `date` command, which is external to `awk`. The `date` command has a feature that can output the day of the week in numeric format, so if you type on the command line `date +%u`, you will get today's day of the week, starting from *Monday*. For the day of the week of another day, use the `d` option, for instance `date -d2018-02-22 +%u`. There is also format code `+%A` for your locale's name of the day of the week, eg 'Thursday'. See the man page for details and many other goodies of the `date` command.

You then have a choice. You could iterate over the `date` command, printing the result for each day of the month, or you could iterate natively in whatever scripting or programming language you feel comfortable with. For instance, you could use the modulus mathematical operator `%` to loop over seven days of the week `n%7` and use a form of `case` statement for your print operation, or you could define a seven element array of names of days of the week. As an example, here is how to define and use an array in `bash`:

```
 dow=( Sun Mon Tues Wed Thu Fri Sat ) ; printf "%s\n" ${dow[4]}
```

What's left is to tell your loop when to stop, ie. how many days are in the month you are processing. That's probably easiest with an array of twelve elements, each containing the number of days in that month. You would need an external test to check for the 29-day February of a leap year.

As for using `awk`, you *could* use it, but it is unlikely to be the best tool for the job because it is designed as a stream editor, and you aren't processing a stream. However, if your assignment *requires* `awk`, then that is what you will be stuck with.

Comment: Thanx a lot :) . I am trying it now. I will paste the code as soon as I do it.

Comment: @KharabelaBhat: Why? This is a question and answer site, not a "snippet wiki". Once the question has been answered, you should check-mark it answered and move on.